# Clickable Cardview to open another activity

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

[MyAdapter.kt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTvEy.png)

im a beginner in this and how to open another activity when i click the cardview..previously it worked fine,but when i click the card nothing happens and only toast show up
I want the user to be able to click on a card and go to a different activity. If you click on card 1 you must go to the activity1. If you click on card 2 you must go to the activity2. Etc...

````
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
import androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.card_item.view.*

class MyAdapter(private val context: Context, private val myModelArrayList: ArrayList<MyModel>) : PagerAdapter(){

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return myModelArrayList.size //return list of records/items
    }

    override fun isViewFromObject(view: View, `object`: Any): Boolean {
        return view == `object`
    }

    override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {
        //inflate layout card_item.xml
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.card_item, container, false)

        //get data
        val model = myModelArrayList.get(position)
        val title = model.title
        val description = model.description
        val date = model.date
        val image = model.image

        //set data to ui views
        view.bannerIv.setImageResource(image)
        view.titleTv.text = title
        view.descriptionTv.text = description
        view.dateTv.text = date

        view.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(context, SecondActivity::class.java)

            context.startActivity(intent)
            // finish();
        }




        //handle item/card click
        view.setOnClickListener{
            Toast.makeText(context,"$title \n $description \n $date", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()


        }

        //add view to container
        container.addView(view, position)
        return view



    }



    override fun destroyItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, `object`: Any) {
        container.removeView(`object` as View)
    }





}
```
````

Comment: The second time you call view.setOnClickListener actually overwrites the first one. Therefore, when a click event is fired only the toast shows up. Just put the code inside the second onClickListener inside the first onClickListener.

Comment: @because_im_batman Its Work!! Thank you so much bro, and how can i add different activity in each item?

Comment: Just use a conditional branching inside your onClickListener. sth like: if (the clicked item is card x) { route to activity x }

Answer (score 0):

just simply remove your second view.setOnClickListener and move your toast to first view.setOnClickListener. As others mentioned second listener will be overridden.